# Is there any framework for UI automation testing for Unity3D?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, unit-tests, qa-developer, nunit

Does anyone know any framework that is compatible/integrated with **Unity3D**? I'm interested in **Unit**, **Integrated** and **UI** testing.

Comment: Is there anything that you've already tried.  A quick search returns a number of results from unity3d.com.

Comment: I've tried TestComplete and SeeTest but they are too expensive.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm looking for exactly same thing - automated UI testing for Unity.

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution. Unity Test Tools are non-play tests and I need Runtime tests. Other solutions would be record and play testing frameworks but if you record a test on a certain device with a specific resolution, the test won't run on another device with a different resolution.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm looking for automated UI testing for app, made in Unity. The original Unity new asset for Ui automation is failing.

Comment: You can try  AltUnityTester. The tool inserts a prefab in your game, and lets you write tests in c# python or java. It has a driver that lets you find objects in your unity game and interact with them.

Answer (score 4):

Although I have never used them, it seems [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) released their own set of testing tools.

- See their introduction blogpost [here.](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/12/18/unity-test-tools-released/)
- See their examples [here](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/21/unit-testing-part-1-unit-tests-by-the-book/).
- Get it from the Asset [Store here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13802).
  Contains both Unit and Integration tests, for the UI tests, I think you need to use an image-based-testing tool like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Comment: Yes, but those are unit tests. I am looking for UI tests. Taps and clicks. Normal user behaviour.

Comment: I think the integration tests they speak of are a bit more then just unit-tests. To quote "Integration tests are also the easiest way of starting to write automation tests on a game in development, since they don’t have requirements on the architecture of the code.". For the click tests I only know image-based-testing framework. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087/automated-testing-a-game and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21397/how-common-is-automated-testing-in-game-development. Maybe repeat the question on gamedev.stackexchange.com that community might have exp.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unity Test Tools are not tests that can be run in Runtime. That was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I recently did my master's thesis on automated system testing of programs made with Unity. In my thesis, I evaluated some of the currently used methods and what tools can be used. I also proposed my own testing approach. You can read about it in [my thesis here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5yLGYEoFht6T3NON2w0VU9zajQ/view?usp=sharing)

To quickly summarize I found that capture and replay tools can be used, but they offer very low level of abstraction and thus any small change to the game will result in that the tests should be redone. Therefore using capture and replay tools cannot be used when the game is in development. [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5yLGYEoFht6T3NON2w0VU9zajQ/view?usp=sharing)

In some cases bots can be used, when there is an enemy AI implemented in the game. For example in the case of the EA football game [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBjJD.png) bots were used for testing. They made two AI football teams fight each other.

I ended up using model-based testing approach since it provides large coverage and allows generating any number of test scripts.

The image shows the architecture of the approach I used. I wrote a testing framework, which I used to control the system under test (SUT) and to get the state of the game. The framework connects to scripts running in the program over socket connection. I made the framework open source (the link can be found in the thesis)

[image: Architecture of the testing approach I used]
I used TestCast MBT for modeling and generating the tests. It is a commercial tool, but I was able to model and use the framework with NModel too, which is open source (links are in the thesis).

I am hoping to promote MBT for game testing and if you need any help you can send me an e-mail, which can be found in my profile.

[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5yLGYEoFht6T3NON2w0VU9zajQ/view?usp=sharing) Omar el Ariss, Dianxiang Xu, Santosh Dandey, Bradley Vender, Philip E. McClean, and Brian M. Slator. A systematic capture and replay strategy for testing complex GUI based java applications.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBjJD.png) Fazeel Gareeboo and Christian Buhl. Automated testing: A key factor for success in video game development. case study and lessons learned. 2012. Pacific NW Software Quality Conference

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a UI testing framework recently released on Unity asset store
It is compatible with Unity Canvas UI and can be integrated with other UI solutions [here.](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/72693)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on test framework for UI testing of Unity3d application that's called **Puppetry**. You can find source code [here](https://github.com/GameUnitLab/Puppetry) and its documentation on [Wiki](https://github.com/GameUnitLab/Puppetry/wiki).

Puppetry can find a GameObject by its name and position in the hierarchy, and then emulate interaction with it (Click, SendKeys, DragAndDrop, Swipe, etc). Plus you can get its component to make additional validation.

You can make UI testing in Editor or combine it with Appium, for example, to test the application on mobile devices.
To use it on a device, Puppetry can provide screen coordinates of a GameObject, and you can click on them, or just use Puppetry's click.

The framework is easy to combine with NUnit, XUnit or MSTest.